# redirect 301 country subfolder to frontpage

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, design-patterns

i look for a redirect pattern which redirects all URLs with the slug /at/  to the frontpage of my site.

**example:**

https://www.example.com/at/shop/systeme/alf/product.html

should redirect to:

https://www.example.com/de/shop/  (this is my frontpage)

i have hundrets of urls with /at/ in the slug. All these Urls should redirect (301) to 
https://www.example.com/de/shop/

i hope somebody can help me

best regards

Tom

Comment: show us what u have tried ?

Answer (score 1):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?at/ /de/shop/ [R=301,QSD]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: thanks for this good and fast answer. If I write the following rewrite to my .htaccess

Rewrite Engine on
RewriteRule ^ /? At / / DE / shop / [R = 301, QSD]
 nothing happens. The URLs with the slug / at / are still reachable. any iedeas why?

Comment: Well, "still reachable", what does that mean? Certainly you can request them, but your browser should get redirected. If not then something is not working. Did you check the hints I gave in the answer? Did you check if you placed the rule in a location that is actually evaluated by the http server? How did you do that? And what do your http servers error and access log files say about those requests?